# Table for a Cayley diagram

Tags: abstract-algebra

My textbook is asking me to write the table of the group having the following Cayley diagram  taking any point to represent *e*:

[image]

The dashed arrow is a multiplication by $a$, the solid arrow is a multiplication by $b$.

If I choose the top point to be $e$ and go counterclockwise, I get the sequence
$e, a, ab, aba, (ab)^2, (ab)^2a, (ab)^3$. If I go clockwise, I get $e,b,ba,bab,(ba)^2,(ba)^2b,(ba)^3$.

Then I conclude that

$e=(ba)^3=(ab)^3\\
(ba)^2a=a\\
(ba)^2=ab\\
aba=bab\\
(ab)^2=ba\\
(ab)^2a=b$

Now I'm confused how to write the table, given that each point has two values. Can I choose any value?

If I name the points $e, a, b, ab, ba, bab$, do I then just follow the diagram to fill out the table? This way the second row would be $ae=a, aa=e, ab=ab, a(ab)=b, a(bab)=ba, a(ba)=bab$.

Comment: Looking into https://vixra.org/abs/1406.0183 there are only 2 groups of order 6, and for the one that is a cycle, the square of a generator is the element "after" the square along the circle. So it seems in the Cayley diagram either all edges must be dashes or all full lines (??)

Comment: Surely it's clear that $a^2=e$ and $b^2=e$? And I don't believe $ab=ba$, they're not the same point in the diagram.

Comment: The elements in this group can indeed be written in several ways as products of the two generators. You are free to choose which. To be consistent you could always go counterclockwise, so all your non-identity elements start with $a$ to give $\{e, a, ab, aba, abab, ababa\}$. Or you could choose the shortest path, giving $\{e, a, ab, aba, ba, b\}$ where I chose $aba$ over $bab$.

Comment: @R.J.Mathar Those are cycle graphs, not Cayley graphs. In a Cayley graph all vertices must have the same degree. If you were to choose $\{(123),(12)\}$ as generators for $S_3$, you'd get a triangular prism Cayley graph. The graph in this question is also for $S_3$ but with the generators $\{(12),(23)\}$ for example.